# Мерцание при Shared Transition

Tags: android

Передаю элементы с помощью Transition

```
                        Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create((View)v.findViewById(R.id.main_card), "transition");
                        Pair<View, String> p2 = Pair.create(v.findViewById(R.id.text_country), "transition1");
                        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                                makeSceneTransitionAnimation(ChooseLocationPanel.this, p1, p2);
                        // start the new activity
                        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Получаю мерцание при переходе. Причем я вижу на миг заставку splash screen которая была ранее. 
Вот так это выглядит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал то, что описано в этом посте, не помогло
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600263/how-do-i-prevent-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-from-animating-during-an-acti

Как можно устранить мерцание?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Все дело в том, что перемещаемый объект не может быть корневым. В остальном все работает теперь как нужно